# Prestashop custom page with own template

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am running my own prestashop theme and want to add a new page without the css.
Therefore I added the three files php, controller and template. I placed the php in the root directory of my prestashop, added the controller to root/controllers/front and placed the template in root/themes/my-theme.
If I call http://localhost/prestashop/?page=custom-page, I see the index start page, If I call localhost/prestashop/custom-page, I get a HTTP 404.
Can someone help me to get my page displayed?

PHP:

```
<?php
  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
  Tools::displayFileAsDeprecated();

  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php');

  $smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'custom-page.tpl');

  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.php');
```

Controller:

```
public function init(){
  parent::init();
}

public function initContent(){
  parent::initContent();
  $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'custom-page.tpl');
}


//public function setMedia(){
  //parent::setMedia();
  //$this->addCSS(_THEME_CSS_DIR_.'custom-page.css');
  //$this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'custom-page.js');
//}
```

}

Template:

```
<div>
 HELLO PAGE
</div>

{literal}
  <style type="text/css">
  </style>
{/literal}

<script type="text/javascript">
  {literal}
  {/literal}
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For PS 1.7, create a new page following the next steps:

**Create the controller**: `/controllers/front/MyPageController.php`

```
<?php

class MyPageControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'mypage';
    public $ssl = true;

    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent();

        $this->setTemplate('mypage');
    }
}
```

**Create the tpl file in your theme**: `/themes/YOUR_THEME/templates/mypage.tpl`

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}

{block name='page_header_container'}{/block}

{block name='page_content'}
  PAGE CONTENT HERE
{/block}
```

**Delete the class index files**: `/var/cache/dev/class_index.php` and `/var/cache/prod/class_index.php`

**How to access it**: `http://your-site.com/index.php?controller=mypage`

**Finally**:
If you want to handle a friendly URL for this page, just add the page in `Shop Parameters > Traffic & SEO`.

Comment: Could you tell me where I need to place the files when I am using my custom theme?

Comment: In PS 1.6 / 1.5 normally in the root of the theme. In PS 1.7 some of them in the root and other one in a sub-folder. In the `/controller/front/ControllerName.php` you can see the path in the property `$this->setTemplate('path/here');`

Comment: hi, so i added it (it was in the list so i guess prestashop knows it is there). how can I call it?

Comment: Could you tell me first which PS version you are using?

Comment: I am using 1.7.X (i think it is actually 1.7.4)

Comment: @ItFreak I have updated my answer to put step by step the process to follow, now I think it should be much clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this! One more question :) I my HTML content I have two images. Is it possible to make them "selectable" via the admin panel?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try this! One more question :) I my HTML content I have two images. Is it possible to make them "selectable" via the admin panel?

Comment: @ItFreak I really don't understand your question, but if this is not about this issue, please create a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Just a little problem, inside the page content block I created a div with content works, but there is nothing displayed on the page :/. I think adding CSS and JS works like I had in mz question example?

Comment: The content should be inside the `page_content` block, NOT outside it, as my example.

Comment: Yea I did : {block name=...} <div>... </div>{/block}

Comment: It should works, maybe you are using a CSS class which is hidden the element, try checking if the HTML code exist in the source code of the page.

Comment: It was just some caching fault. I repeated the cache delete and it works now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice would be to create a module with your custom page. Because with your approach you may get troubles after prestashop update and also a behavior of your store may be unpredictable with different properties.

Here is some information about how to create own page within a module https://belvg.com/blog/creating-frontcontroller-in-the-module-and-customization-of-displaying-page-in-prestashop.html and https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-implement-a-controller.html

Comment: thanks, I followed another tutorial of this blog to create those files. Now I added it under SEO (so I think prestashop know that it is 'there'), how can I call the page?

Comment: Use $link = new Link(); $link->getModuleLink('your_module', 'controller', $params); for module or $link->getPageLink('controller') for that method with a custom page crating you have tryed. If you have implemented everything correctly it should work

Comment: And where can I see this link?

Comment: If you are using a module you can define a variable and pass it to your front-end. Something like $customPage = $link->getModuleLink('your_module', 'controller', $params); And use it in your tpl like <a href="$customPage"></a>. Or if you are using custome page variant you need to add it in the classes/controller/FrontController.php to the method getTemplateVarUrls in the array $p(which contains pages names) and use it in your templates like $urls.pages.custom_page