# Prestashop - how to create a custom page?

Tags: prestashop

Title says it all. I want to create a custom prestashop page, but I don't know how. 
What I actually want to do: create a button that opens a custom page. I can't find anything useful in the internet so I came here to ask for help. Could someone explain me how to do that?

Comment: What Prestashop version are you talking about? I guess you need a custom front page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to add a new page, it depending in your needs.

1. By a CMS page, you can add the content you need in the HTML editor, like the product description: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/CMS+-+Managing+Static+Content
2. By a front controller from a module: https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/
3. By creating a new page, here my explanation: [Prestashop custom page with own template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278754/prestashop-custom-page-with-own-template/#answer-52281093)

The point 1 is the most easy way for a common user, the rest of the points require advanced knowledge.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Point 2 and 3 is exactly what I was looking for.